# Icon inside a circle not aligning centre, horizontal and vertical aligning properly on browser < 100%

Tags: html, css, responsive-design

I am using icoMoon fonts (https://icomoon.io/) and centre aligning horizontally and vertically inside circle. Its looking in centre in 100% and 80% of browser but when  < 80% the icon is not aligning properly. Simliar case, with > 100% of browser(chrome);

Attaching screenshots:-

[image]

[image]

```css
.uniIcon {
  height: 18px;
  width: 18px;
  line-height: 18px;
  border-radius: 100%;
  text-align: center;
  float: left;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  position: relative;
}

.iconmoon-icon-files {
  font-size: 12px;
  color: #FFF;
  vertical-align: sub;
  padding-left: 1px;
}
```

```html
<div class="uniIcon" style="background-color: #161620;"><i class="iconmoon-icon-files"></i></div>
```

Comment: I just created snippet for you from your code, I don't see any icons inside.

Comment: Its create using icoMoon https://icomoon.io/  and in local.

Answer (score 0):

Try setting line height for icons to align them in div center, something like

```
.iconmoon-icon-files {
  font-size: 12px;
  color: #FFF;
  line-height:inherit;
}
```

Inherit will make line-height of icon take on the height of its containing div.